# Can TorchServer support dynamic batch_size?

Tags: pytorch

When register a model in TorchServer, batch_size need to be set, otherwise batch_size is set as 1, can TorchServer support dynamic batch_size?

Comment: I am just curious is this for Computer Vision Task?

Comment: Yes, i found TorchServer need to set max batch_size, however client may send any num of images